# How to remove a string with specific pattern without using REGEX?

Tags: python, string, file

I am having a difficult time with these sets of inputs and  outputs:

```
input: so sh [/] she had a [^ wheee] .
output: so sh [/] she had a .

input: aah [!] [^ makes sound effects] .
output: aah.

input: and she say (.) I got it [^ repeats 2 times] .
output: and she say (.) I got it .

input: oh no[x 3] .
output: oh  no.


input: xxx [^ /bosolasafiso/]
output: xxx

input: hi [* med]
oupt: hi [* med]
```

I have used REGEX but no use, I need exact conditions to make all these satisfy and the resultant output should be returned.

All the "INPUTS" are being read from a file so please be noted that even if i use "split()" the words like [^ whee] will be treated as two different words.

I need a condition where only words that contains  `[/] [*` should be retained.
other words that starts with "[" should be replaced with an empty string.

Comment: what regex pattern did you use?

Comment: I used (\[\*\s\w*\]) and (\[\/\])

Comment: @hjpotter92 And I need help with any regular expression that returns the words that starts exactly with "[*" and ends with "]"  or "[\" "]" but it may contain any number of words inside "[* ]"  or "[\ ]" this pattern

Comment: You can regex replace `[/X]` and `[*X]` with a placeholder of your choice (say, `{/X}` and `{*X}`), then replace all `[Y]` with an empty string, and finally replace the curly braces with square brackets again.

Comment: @DYZ that's a good idea but if you see these inputs and outputs clearly you can note that [/x] is not a single word it is two words "[*" and  "x]" so how can this logic be done? that is I have to change "[*" to "{*" and the next word will not always be "X" in all the cases, So how to change the next word of the end of the string to '}"?

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works, assuming that there are **no** curly braces in your original text. Otherwise, use some other pair of delimiters (e.g., `<<` and `>>`).

```
s1 = 'so sh [/] [* med] she had a [^ wheee] .'
```

First, replace `[` and `]` in each `[/ X]` or `[* X]` fragment with a `{` and `}`, respectively, to protect them from elimination. Then eliminate all survising fragments in square brackets. Finally, replace all curly braces back to square brackets:

```
re.sub(r"\[[^]]*]", "", # Remove [Y] blocks
        re.sub(r"\[([/*][^]]*)]", r"{\1}", s1)) # Rename [X] to {X}\
  .replace("{", "[") # Restore the original brackets\
  .replace("}", "]")
#'so sh [/] [* med] she had a  .'
```

Comment: It worked thanks a lot for your help! Can you please explain it or give me a referal link?

Comment: It's all about the functions `re.sub()` and `str.replace()`. In fact, the latter could be avoided because `re.sub()` is more universal. The documentation for both functions is available online, you can google it.